# Understanding Win 8's Search Function

Tags: search, windows-search

I was looking for my resume under the MOUNDS of folders I have in my file system but couldn't locate it.

I knew the file containted the word "resume" so I cracked into the robustness of the Win 8 search function to locate this lost file.

Unfortunately Win8 turned up absolutely nothing and worse than that it returned file names that didn't even contain the string "resume"

To make doubly sure I Ofcourse prefixed the search with a wildcard character and Win8 found my resume but this doesn't seem intuitive. Joe PC user would never use a wildcard and if he lost a file he would perform a most primitive search using standard strings.

Can anybody shed some light on the innerworkings of the Win8 search function? Why did it not locate my file with a basic string search? I felt this to be a most basic search and by default Win8 couldn't locate what I was looking for even though the file contained the string I searched with.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8's search utility will not search what is not in your libraries, or is not an app or setting. Therefore, inserting the wildcard is why it made it index that particular file.